# Creating stable increments for x axis in a graph

Tags: math, graph, axis

I am showing an animated graph, with time as the x axis -- and need to give it some labels.

At time `t` the x axis ranges from `0 to t`, it's not a sliding window.

There are two obvious solutions:

a) Label every second

This doesn't work, because when t gets big, my graph is unreadable with so many x labels.

b) Divide the `t` by 5, and use that as an increment.

This works instantaneously, but on an animated graph is completely unusable due to the instability (and ugliness of the numbers chosen).

So what I am looking for, is a function of `t` that returns five numbers I can use for labeling the x axis of my graph.

These numbers should be:

- attractive `(e.g. 50, 100, 150, 200, 250)`
- roughly evenly spread out between `0` and `t` (i.e. `[t, t-1, t-2, t-3, t-4]` is a non-solution).
- **stable** so that as t progresses, people only see values from the x axis drop off, and new values slide it. But they don't see the numbers on the x axis bounce around

It's not required that they are all exactly the same width apart.

Answer (score 2):

I'll argue that the requirement of always having *exactly* five labels might be a showstopper. Most people will consider stepwidths following the pattern 1,2,5,10,20,50,100,200,500,… But if you do this in your case, you will often be dropping 4/10 of the labels while just introducing a single new one. So what I'd do instead is consider the stepwidths listed above, and switch to the next higher stepwidth whenever there is room for at least two steps at that width. So when you reach t=100 you'd switch from 20,40,60,80 to 50,100. You may of course fine-tune the switchover rule if having more labels is acceptable. This still means introducing new numbers on the axis at positions where they don't slide in. If that's a real problem, then you have to use either the sequence 1,2,10,20,100,200,… or 1,5,10,50,100,500,… since then every step width will be a multiple of the step width before it. This will however entail even bigger jumps in the number of labels.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It's not so much that I need them exactly one apart, but I would like the property that "one slides in, one drops off". Maybe it's in my head, but I imagine that would look very slick